# How does CSS shorthand for background:url work

Tags: css

I'm trying to modify the css for an application from oracle.I'm trying to decipher the below css entry.
Particularly I'm interested to find out that 49% -165px does. Is it the X and Y co-ordinates?

```
.siebui-self-service {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: url('../../../images/custom/image.jpg') no-repeat 49% -165px;
background-color: #8aaeba;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 49% is referring to position from right and -165px is referring to position from top.

The `background` property is shorthand for all the background-based properties and the syntax is like this:

> background: color image repeat position;

where

`background-color` e.g. `#FFFFFF`

`background-image` e.g. `url("image.png")`

`background-repeat` e.g. `no-repeat`

`background-position` e.g. `49% -165px` referring to right/top

from w3schools:

> It does not matter if one of the property values is missing, as long as the ones that are present are in this order.

Comment: I see. I was thinking the 49% was the size and -165x was x co-ordinate. That make sense. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. If you found this helpful would you be kind enough to accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I added this to a quick test page. Chrome dev tools translated that background style to:

```
    background: url('../../../images/custom/image.jpg') no-repeat 49% -165px;
        background-image: url(http://localhost:6969/images/custom/image.jpg);
        background-position-x: 49%;
        background-position-y: -165px;
        background-size: initial;
        background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
        background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: initial;
        background-origin: initial;
        background-clip: initial;
        background-color: initial;
```